# How to plot the confusion matrix with python

Tags: python, data-mining, confusion-matrix

I am trying to plot the confusion matrix, but I get an error: 
 `TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf_mat'` 
Here is what I have tried

```
cm_des_tree = [[5,0,0,0,0],[3,20,1,0,0],[0,0,4,1,0],[0,3,0,31,0],[0,1,2,0,41]]
target_names = ['Q1', 'E1', 'Q2', 'E2', 'P']

fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=cm_des_tree,
                                colorbar=True,
                                show_absolute=False,
                                show_normed=True,
                                class_names=target_names)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I do not know the lib you use, but I would recommend just to dig into declaration of the function plot_confusion_matrix and check arguments used in it. Probably named arg is different

Comment: I use `from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix`. What lib do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `plot_confusion_matrix`, you pass it the estimator, followed by the independent variables, then labels, modifying the example from the [vignette](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
clf = SVC(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X, y)
```

[image]

It looks like you already have the confusion matrix, one option is to use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y,clf.predict(X)), annot=True)
```

[image]

Using your dataset:

```
cm_des_tree = [[5,0,0,0,0],[3,20,1,0,0],[0,0,4,1,0],[0,3,0,31,0],[0,1,2,0,41]]
target_names = ['Q1', 'E1', 'Q2', 'E2', 'P']
sns.heatmap(cm_des_tree, annot=True,xticklabels=target_names,yticklabels=target_names)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @StupidWolf, I got it.